# Why the output is 4 and not 16 in this C code?

Tags: c, pointers, bit-fields

I dont understand why the output of this code is 4 and not 16, Assuming that `unsigned int` takes 4 bytes and `long int` takes 8 bytes. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    unsigned int x;
    long int y : 33;
    unsigned int z;
};

int main()
{
    struct test t;
    unsigned int* ptr1 = &t.x;
    unsigned int* ptr2 = &t.z;
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe `ptr2 - ptr1` is strictly speaking undefined behavior as they are not two pointers pointing at the same array. Although if you cast to a character type it should be ok and then you get the size in bytes too.

Comment: The C standard does not require the type used for declaring a bit-field to have any effect on either the semantics of the bit-field (how it behaves in expressions) or the size of storage used to hold it, except that `_Bool` bit-field acts like a `_Bool`. Even if `long int` is 8 bytes, your `long int y : 33` bit-field is allowed to take fewer or more bytes.

Comment: But wait, there is more! The offset between 2 struct member also depends on struct packing. Which is controlled by compiler arguments. Use "pack 8" and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you expected the output to be 16, because the offset between the pointers should be 16 bytes (assuming sizes are as you mentioned in your question).

But in c when you subtract pointers, you don't get the number of bytes but the number of **elements**. The elements are the data the pointers point to.
Since these are `unsigned int` pointers, and assuming `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4, the difference between thr pointers is 4 elements.

**However** - as @Lundin commented above this theoretical claculation is not really relevant because subtrating pointers that do not point the same array is **UB** ([undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

BTW - Note when you add an integral value to a pointer, a similar thing happens on the other way: the result is the address of the pointer plus the integral value times the size of the element pointed by the pointer. E.g.: if you add 1 to `unsigned int* ptr1`, the resulting address will be higher than `ptr1` by 4.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response, but i dont understand what do you mean by elements?

Comment: Elements are what the pointers point to (in your case `unsigned int` values). This might be clearer when you consider the case when you add e.g. 1 to a `unsigned int` pointer. In this case the address will be incremented by 4.